# Check if a row exists in sql server database then delete using vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

***Problem:***  I am currently using a vb application(Visual Studio 2012) to query my database (SQL Server 2012) to check if the row exists in a table if the row does exist then delete it. However if it does not exist then add the row to the database.

***Additional information:*** I have text boxes on my vb application with the data. This data is saved to the database.

I have complied the code and cannot seem to find the error in the line of code.
Please find the code below!

***Code:***

```
cmd2.CommandText = 
 "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM(tblLocation) WHERE Tag_ID = '" 
 & txttags.Text 
 & "') THEN (DELETE FROM tblLocation WHERE Tag_ID = '" 
 & txttags.Text 
 & ")' ELSE INSERT INTO tblLocation([Area], [Area_Time], [TagID]) VALUES('" 
 & txtLocation.Text & "' , '" 
 & txtdate.Text & "','" & txttags.Text & "')"
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please please please read about sql injection attacks http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev . If you gave me your application I could wipe out your database!

Comment: Will take a look at it! don't want that to happen!

Comment: it's a big article - but I'd suggest you read it, the key piece of information to take home is parameterised queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis before/after the DELETE statement as follows:

```
cmd2.CommandText = 
    "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblLocation WHERE Tag_ID = '" 
    & txttags.Text 
    & "') DELETE FROM tblLocation WHERE Tag_ID = '" 
    & txttags.Text 
    & "' ELSE INSERT INTO tblLocation([Area], [Area_Time], [TagID]) VALUES('" 
    & txtLocation.Text & "' , '" 
    & txtdate.Text & "','" & txttags.Text & "')"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Still coming up with a error after compiling it.

Comment: I removed the parenthesis around the table name on the select.

Comment: apologies just realized i didn't post the error! thanks wdosanjos! the error is saying Incorrect syntax near ')'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: Also removed keyword `THEN` (not valid in T-SQL).

Comment: Thank you so much it is now working! spent ages looking at it! sometimes you just a fresh pair of eyes to look at it!